# jbossfuse: Cannot find the declaration of element 'blueprint'

Tags: jbossfuse

While Deploying a War application into fuse container, Im getting the Exception: **cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'blueprint'**

My blueprint schema is:

```
<blueprint
xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
```

Exception detail:

```
 org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 4.3.0 | Error deploying web application
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/camel-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'blueprint'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:397)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)[310:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)[310:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)[205:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)[310:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)[310:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)[310:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$3.call(HttpServiceContext.java:354)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$3.call(HttpServiceContext.java:350)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.ContextClassLoaderUtils.doWithClassLoader(ContextClassLoaderUtils.java:60)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.callContextInitialized(HttpServiceContext.java:349)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.startContext(HttpServiceContext.java:601)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:260)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[96:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:279)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1096)[116:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:417)[116:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:380)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:692)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:317)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:101)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:219)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:179)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:59)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender$1.run(AbstractExtender.java:281)[276:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:4.3.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'blueprint'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:201)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:132)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:394)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:282)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2143)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:788)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:283)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:733)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1754)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:875)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:230)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:298)[:2.11.0.SP4-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:389)[203:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
    ... 49 more
```

Can anyone give a clue in this scenario?

Comment: Looks like you mix Spring and OSGi Blueprint together in the WAR - you should not really do that. On JBoss Fuse you should favour deploying non-war files, but deploy regular OSGi bundles or karaf features.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

In JBoss FUSE the war isn't a preferred way, you should use bundle instead, and use blueprint to configure the route. Please take a look at the camel quickstarts in JBoss FUSE kit.